# Use of mode for a transform in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this datataset:

```py
thedf = pd.DataFrame({'id':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A',
                            'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                      'group':['X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y',
                               'X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y'],
                     'value':['Ball','Coin','Coin','Coin','Yoyo','Yoyo','Toy','Puzzle',
                              'Ham','Grape','Ham','Ham','Pear','Pear','Pear','Ham']})
    id  group   value
0   A   X       Ball
1   A   X       Coin
2   A   X       Coin
3   A   X       Coin
4   A   Y       Yoyo
5   A   Y       Yoyo
6   A   Y       Toy
7   A   Y       Puzzle
8   B   X       Ham
9   B   X       Grape
10  B   X       Ham
11  B   X       Ham
12  B   Y       Pear
13  B   Y       Pear
14  B   Y       Pear
15  B   Y       Ham
```

And I try to apply a transform to get the most frequent item on a two level group, so the expected result is:

```py
    id  group   value    mode
0   A   X       Ball     Coin
1   A   X       Coin     Coin
2   A   X       Coin     Coin
3   A   X       Coin     Coin
4   A   Y       Yoyo     Yoyo
5   A   Y       Yoyo     Yoyo
6   A   Y       Toy      Yoyo
7   A   Y       Puzzle   Yoyo
8   B   X       Ham      Ham
9   B   X       Grape    Ham
10  B   X       Ham      Ham
11  B   X       Ham      Ham
12  B   Y       Pear     Pear
13  B   Y       Pear     Pear
14  B   Y       Pear     Pear
15  B   Y       Ham      Pear
```

So I tried this:

```py
thedf['mode'] = thedf.groupby(['id','group'])['value'].transform('mode')
```

But it returns this error: `ValueError: 'mode' is not a valid function name for transform(name)`

What am I missing here? Should I write a custom function for this? Any hint will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `mode` returns.a series, and doesn't have a string name. So `.transform(lambda x: x.mode[0])`.

Comment: Hello @QuangHoang, after applying the proposed solution it mentions: `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I mean `x.mode()[0]`.

Comment: Thank you very much @QuangHoang, now I can get the second most frequent value too (I think mode returns a list, so I can access its elements by index). Have a great day!